# How can I redirect without infinite loop in PHP code?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have two WordPress sites using the multi-site function, the URLs are below:

- A: sample.com
- B: sample.com/en

I tried to write a code in PHP following these conditions, but when I access the RUL of A:sample.com, a browser(chrome) shows an error.

So would you mind telling me how should I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

---

**the conditions for access**

- The first access is only to [A: sample.com]
- Users whose browser language is set to Japanese access to [A:
  sample.com]
- All users whose browser language setting is not set to Japanese
  access [B: sample.com/en]

---

**The errors messages in the browser(chrome)**

```
This page isn’t working
sample.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

---

**The code for adding in functions.php**

```
<?php
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $BASE_LANG = 'en';

    if (!preg_match('/^[!-~][a-zA-Z]{2}[!-~]/', $uri)) {
        $languages = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
        $lang = $BASE_LANG;
        if (isset($languages)) {
            $browser_lamguage = $languages[0];
            $base_languages = array('ja', 'en');

            foreach ($base_languages as $base_language) {
                if (preg_match("/^$base_language/i", $browser_lamguage)) {
                    $lang = $base_language;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        $url = get_site_url()."/$lang/";
        if ($lang == 'ja') {
            $url = get_site_url();
        }
        header("Location: $url");
        exit();
    }
?>
```

---

**Development environment**

- CentOS (7 x86_64)
- Apache (2.4.6 CentOS)
- PHP (7.1.33)
- wordpress(5.2.5)

Answer (score 0):

Just make below change in your code:

```
if ($lang != 'ja') {
    header("Location: $url");
    exit();
}
```

Edited:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$BASE_LANG = 'en';

if (!preg_match('/^[!-~][a-zA-Z]{2}[!-~]/', $uri)) {
    $languages = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
    $lang = $BASE_LANG;
    if (isset($languages)) {
        $browser_lamguage = $languages[0];
        $base_languages = array('ja', 'en');

        foreach ($base_languages as $base_language) {
            if (preg_match("/^$base_language/i", $browser_lamguage)) {
                $lang = $base_language;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    $url = get_site_url()."/$lang/";
    if ($lang != 'ja') {
        header("Location: $url");
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed the code as your advice, in the case of browser, language is set to Japanese access to sample.com/ja/ and makes it 404 error, in the case browser language setting is not set to Japanese redirect to [B: sample.com/en], and work well

Comment: thank you for your help, Yes please could you share the whole code? and I will try it once again.